# Git commit returns "nothing to commit"

Tags: git, commit

I am following instructions from
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#what_is_heroku

I have edited the file once already and pushed the changes successfully to the app.
But when I tried to make the second change and do another push; it failed at the commit step.

I get the error "On branch master nothing to commit  working directory clean"
the previous steps work just fine.

Clone works fine
Git remote returns Heroku alright

I have tried git add. before the commit; and git pull (which returns alread up-to-date).

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please post the complete command list you are using including a `git status`.

Comment: Is what you're editing actually under version control?  Or is it being ignored via `.gitignore`?  Are you editing a file in a different location accidentally?  Does `git ls-files` show the file you edited in your listing?

Comment: BTW, that is not an error message, just a note that there is nothing to do.

Comment: Before pushing the code use "git status" to check which files have changed since the last commit. Then add the files you want using "git add <file-names>". When you have added the files use "git commit". "git commit -a" will add all the files which have the changes (so u don't have to add the files manually)but remember this will not add newly added files.